# Make digital sign of xml-nodes by X509 certificate on iOS

Tags: objective-c, digital-signature, x509

I have an X509 certificate in my key chain on iOS. 
How I can make (and write) digital signature of xml, as xml. Not as string. I need secure by digital signature only individual nodes of XML document.
How I can do it on Objective-C?

```
    <eps:Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:eps="urn-zaoeps-schemas-docmanagement">
  <eps:DocumentData Id="{2c477639-f9ef-4955-91fb-ca8713ae8e31}">
    <eps:DocumentNumber>19</eps:DocumentNumber>
    <eps:Customer>Coca-Cola</eps:Customer>
    <eps:Topic>5</eps:Topic>
    <eps:Vendor>Peroni</eps:Vendor>
    <eps:Subject>Glass</eps:Subject>
    <eps:SignedAttachments>
      <eps:Attachment Name="Brif" DbId="{540880e7-96cd-4173-a76b-e42653f11af1}" IsApproved="false" Extension="doc">
        <eps:RelativePath>/540880e796cd4173a76be42653f11af1/Brif.doc</eps:RelativePath>
        <eps:Hash>1QBSw0+kbRbVGcHSbJIMuyQF8OA=</eps:Hash>
      </eps:Attachment>
    </eps:SignedAttachments>
  </eps:DocumentData>
  <eps:SignatureContainer>
    <eps:Signatures>
      <Signature Id="{82116185-ac2a-4af4-9d9d-ac304b4c20ed}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="#{2c477639-f9ef-4955-91fb-ca8713ae8e31}">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>EmL07BOUnxW6QNgo5iTmKUtq2RQ=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#{e138da73-a971-4de2-b3a2-d050e53bfcdc}">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>0Ivb7ArrzbEQ/QqC0f3isk9bf9c=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>oa3dYTM8yvrNUFytNWWLtSwoeRNhGe5R8DU/wVrx2nP2yxyxXOy5oHlnfkPkbBy4OWahm914QaShfpnVQVjvf1emYLgTG8swECVYDulyH97/vgJ+IUe8uMjyFnZWpTt2xBVoqprUSWRBUriXr5pAxqDLMYzgHazOB8LOJ3wIf5k=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
......
```

Comment: You need some XMLDSig library for iOS. I can mention only our SecureBlackbox and I am not sure if there exist any alternatives for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you need to do exactly, but here are some library references that might help you.

[GDataXML](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/) is a XML parser and creator by google.

[OAuth Obj-c](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/OAuthConsumer/) has some useful classes like OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider for.

[Apple's Encryption Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html)